# information about honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

i find that there are only two videos that showed at CES2011 on internet and no other information about it. Such as which linux do honeycomb use.

Does anyone know more about the honeycomb?

thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can now get a lot more information via the Honeycomb developer preview site at http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0-highlights.html

Answer (score 1):

You can find out more about Android 3.0 here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0.html

And here's the API difference report:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/11/changes.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29), honeycomb is going to possess following features:

```
* Optimized tablet support with a new user interface
* Three dimensional desktop with redesigned widgets
* Refined multi-tasking
* Browser enhancements including tabbed web pages, form auto-fill, bookmark syncing with Google Chrome, and private browsing
* Support for video chat using Google Talk
```